# New 'Recommendation' Dialog Box Appears When User Hits 'Like' Button

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I'm hoping that someone can help me out with this problem that I've been trying to solve all day. It appears as though there is a new 'Like' button on certain Facebook Fan Pages. When a user hits this button a dialog box appears that says.... "Help your friends discover great places to visit by writing a recommendation for 'Fan Page Name'". There is space to include a recommendation and 2 buttons; 'recommend' or 'skip'.

My team have developed a fangated promotion for this client (which lives on a separate canvas page). With the typical 'Like' button functionality the user likes the page and is automatically taken to the canvas page promotion. As a result of this new 'Like' button (whether the user chooses to recommend or not) the are automatically redirected back to the main Wall and can only access the canvas promotion by clicking on the correct icon in the left column.(Needless to say this is resulting in a lot of traffic being lost.)

I have 3 questions here;

1. Any ideas on how to remove this 'Recommend' dialog box and revert back to the normal 'Like' button
2. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to allow the user click 'Like' (recommend or not) and arrive at the correct canvas page without the redirect back to the Wall?
3. Do you have any insight on how FB are choosing which pages to roll this new 'Like' button out to?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It's a facebook bug for places pages

temporary workaround is to remove the address from your fan page ... still looking for a coding workaround so please post if you have one!!